# Issues running the rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to use jobsworth and run into an issue with the schema not properly generating. I submitted a report, got a stock reply of "We fixed it for next release" (which they have been saying for over 5 months now) and a nice little workaround using rake. shame the rake command doesn't work.

So I run bundle install:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make
sh: 1: make: not found


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Fantastic. Then I try installing RedCloth:

```
ERROR:  Error installing RedCloth:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make
sh: 1: make: not found


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
```

I've looked around for many solutions and most are related to errors with Octopress or on Macs, and I'm not using either so they aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that `make` is not installed. If it's not installed, install it. If it is installed, add the directory containing the `make` binary to to `$PATH` and try again.

Comment: This is why I don't use linux often. -_- That fixed it. I got some new errors now, but at least I fixed one part.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem when deploying my project via Puppet.

In my case, even though `make` is present and all related libraries are installed, `$PATH` is set correctly for `root` and other users, running `bundle install` via `exec` resource in Puppet (see below) resulted in this very same error:

```
class bundler_run ($target) {
  exec { 'get bundle':
  path        => [ '/bin', '/usr/local/bin', '/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin' ],
  cwd         => $target,
  unless      => "bundle check > /dev/null",
  command     => 'bundle install --deployment --clean --without development test',
  logoutput   => true,
  }
}
```

My fix for that, was setting `PATH` explicitly in Gemfile

```
ENV['PATH'] = "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Additionally, setting encoding to UTF8, solves `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII` error,

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my problem:

**sudo apt-get install build-essential**